# How to access a file from asset/raw directory

Tags: android, android-assets

with this below code i'm trying to access the file which is stored in `asset/raw` folder, but getting `null` and

```
E/ERR: file:/android_asset/raw/default_book.txt (No such file or directory)
```

error, my code is:

```
private void implementingDefaultBook() {
    String filePath = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/raw/default_book.txt").toString();
    File   file     = new File(filePath);
    try {
        FileInputStream stream      = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERR ", e.getMessage());
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Place your text file in the /assets directory under the Android project and use AssetManager class as follows to access it.

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("default_book.txt");
```

Or you can also put the file in the /res/raw directory, from where the file can be accessed by an id as follows

```
InputStream is = 
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.default_book);
```

Comment: what is context and how do you access it

Comment: @PatrickYoussef basically Context is an object that's used to do anything related to your android app, like getting assets, you'll need a reference of your app to be able to access your app's assets. you can get this object from something like an Activity. read more about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android

Answer (score 14):

Assets and resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device.

For assets, use `open()` on `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` on your asset.

Also, FWIW:

- `Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/raw/default_book.txt").toString()` is pointless, as it gives you the same string that you started with
- `file:///android_asset/` only works for `WebView`

Answer (score 5):

As the actual question wasn't sufficiently answered, here we go

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().openFd("raw/"+"filename.txt")
```

context  can be `this` or `getActivity()` or basically any other context

Important is to include the folder before the filename separated by an `/`

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin we can achieve as-

```
val string = requireContext().assets.open("default_book.txt").bufferedReader().use {
                it.readText()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("default_book.txt");
```