# Getting `File not found` errors for an `asset`. How can this be?

Tags: java, android, assets

I'm about to go nuts with this. I keep getting errors when trying to open a text file that's in my `assets` directory, whose full path name is

```
C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\WordyHelperton - Copy - Copy\
   app\src\main\assets
```

Even though we can SEE filename `Dictionary.dic` in the `assets` folder for my  project...

[image]

... **I keep getting errors that the file doesn't exist:**

``````
W/`````: Can't open <Dictionary.dic>
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Dictionary.dic
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
W/System.err:     at com.dslomer64.servyhelperton.DatabaseConnector$LoadDatabase.doInBackground(DatabaseConnector.java:328)
W/System.err:     at com.dslomer64.servyhelperton.DatabaseConnector$LoadDatabase.doInBackground(DatabaseConnector.java:315)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
``````

Doc says you can use hierarchical name in the open statement:

``````
W/`````: Can't open <C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\WordyHelperton - Copy - Copy\app\src\main\assets\Dictionary.dic>
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\WordyHelperton - Copy - Copy\app\src\main\assets\Dictionary.dic
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
W/System.err:     at com.dslomer64.servyhelperton.DatabaseConnector$LoadDatabase.doInBackground(DatabaseConnector.java:330)
W/System.err:     at com.dslomer64.servyhelperton.DatabaseConnector$LoadDatabase.doInBackground(DatabaseConnector.java:317)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
``````

Same problem.

**Can you see any problem with my code?** The problem HAS to be obvious, but after two days of trying this and that and utterly failing, and it LOOKS so good and therefore MUST be obvious, but I CAN'T SEE IT....

---

I've included this in case it's not obvious from above. If this doesn't help, I'm on my own.

Here is how `DatabaseConnector` gets called in `onCreate` in `MainActivity`:

```
assets = getAssets();

dbc = new DatabaseConnector(getApplicationContext(), assets); // to create DB if needed
```

Here's how `mAssets` and `SOURCE_NAME` are defined; also have `DatabaseConnector` definition and its call to `dbOpenHelper`.

[image]

Here's how `LoadDatabase` is called from `createDbIfNecessary`:

```
  LoadDatabase
      __loadDb;
      __loadDb = new LoadDatabase();
      __loadDb.execute((Object[]) null);
```

*EDIT*

Another opinion:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

**Please note that changing the filename in the code to lowercase doesn't help. AND it's a DOS file, NOT ANDROID. AND File is never leaving drive `C:`**

``````
public static String DATABASE_SOURCE = 
"C:\\Users\\Dov\\Desktop\\ServyHelperton\\app\\src\\main" +
  "\\assets\\dictionary.dic";

W/`````: Can't open <C:\Users\Dov\Desktop\ServyHelperton\app\src\main\assets\dictionary.dic>

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dov\Desktop\ServyHelperton\app\src\main\assets\dictionary.dic
``````

I could add more code to prove what I just said, but trust me. The `DATABASE_SOURCE` name is ALL I changed.

Comment: Check this answer here. It might solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908648/android-get-file-from-asset-raw/45908819#45908819

Comment: I have to vent to whoever downvoted and voted to Close. How can you vote this down WITHOUT REASON? It is ABSOLUTELY CLEAR and it WILL BE USEFUL TO ME if you would just STOOP DOWN TO MY LEVEL AND TELL ME WHAT'S WRONG.
And voting to CLOSE on WHAT GROUNDS? HOW DO YOU KNOW HOW MUCH RESEARCH AND EFFORT WENT INTO GETTING IT THIS FAR? Do you see how much useful help I've received? NONE.Suggestions didn't help, but I appreciated both. So it's NOT THAT CLEAR what the problem is. I saw NO REASON to show all I tried, but THAT was SIGNIFICANT effort. And I looked at AND REFERRED TO DOCS. *How -1, close?*

Comment: Mark, you DID help me by directing my attention to more locally defining `stream` and `sDict`, the `InputStream` and `Scanner`.

Comment: About venting... see my last comment. If all the problem was was the 'D'..... arrgghh.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your path is for Dictionary.dic rather than dictionary.dic

See if that helps

Comment: This.  Android is Linux, and most (if not all) Linux filesystems are case sensitive.

Comment: I know quite well that Linux is case sensitive.  But the file in question is a **DOS** file and is NOT going onto an Android device. AND NOTE that "file was not found" even when all lowercase. So NOW what?

Comment: Your Answer is NOT useful. That's why I have `mContext.getAssets`. Maybe I have the wrong `Context`.

Comment: in your 2nd edit, your path is 


ServyHelperton but in the beginning it was 


WordyHelperton -Copy -Copy , 

did you change it to ServyHelperton or was that the initial one?

Comment: also, and this is bizarre if the case [check that your file isn't failing due to size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder)

Comment: I'm embarrassed. Even though `dictionary.dic` is a Windows file, I'm under the auspices of Android Studio, where cASe dOes MaTter. SO that was a problem. But the size of the file has never been an issue, So I owe an apology to Kevin and Eldar.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the fix was sort of easy or maybe dumb luck, because I'm not sure why making the `InputStream` and `Scanner` local to `doInBackground` cured the problem.

Refer to the first picture in the original Question. I made no significant changes to `MainActivity`, but here is the interesting line in it:

```
dbc = new DatabaseConnector(getApplicationContext(), getAssets());
```

This is what worked:

```
public class DatabaseConnector
{
  static Context mContext;

  public DatabaseConnector(Context _context, AssetManager _assets)
  {
    mAssets   = _assets;
    mContext  = _context;

    mDbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(_context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    createDbIfNecessary();
  }

  private class DbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
  {
    DbOpenHelper(Context _context, String _name, CursorFactory _factory, int _version)
    {
      super(_context, _name, _factory, _version);
    }

    private class LoadDatabase extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void>
    {
      protected Void doInBackground(Object[] params)
      {
        Scanner scDict = null; // ***** MOVING/ADDING THESE 
        InputStream stream;    // ***** TWO LINES HERE WAS KEY
        try{
          stream = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_SOURCE);
          scDict = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\r\n");
        }
        catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(69);}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that EVERY piece of advice, comments AND Answer, were completely wrong. And I'm also sorry that some dork downvoted and voted to close, because it IS A GOOD QUESTION WITH NO OBVIOUS SOLUTION. I'm also sorry that 3 people upvoted the other Answer. Not even close. Upvote, downvote, just don't THINK, is apparently how things are too often done here..

Comment: I'm a jerk. It is NOT TRUE that the advice I received was useless. I'd hate to think that all along the only problem was `D` vs. `d` in  dictionary. That would be impossibly and unbearably embarrassing. I'm tempted to put everything back to the way it was and then see if what I had would have worked with `D`ictionary.com. In THAT case it WAS a stupid question, deserving of both downvote and vote to close. I saw that `D` but said, hey, that's a Windows file. How could case matter? Well, it DOES TO ANDROID. Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa.