# sourceSets with awsconfiguration.json

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-gradle-plugin, aws-amplify, source-sets

I am using AWS Amplify and have two environments that I am switching between, therefore I have two `awsconfiguration.json` files, but need a way to switch between the two at runtime. I've heard you can use sourceSets, but can't figure out how. I tried the following, but with no success. I believe I have to setup a `productFlavor` and/or `buildType`?

```
sourceSets {
    prod {
        res.srcDirs = ['res-prod']
    }

    dev {
        res.srcDirs = ['res-dev']
    }
}
```

Comment: copy these two files in two different folders, then set the target to these folders via build type

Comment: how to create awsconfiguration.json file for push notification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `awsconfiguration.json` under **`assets`** directory per each product flavor, see the directory structure as shown below:

[image]

For how to configure product flavor and build types, please refer to: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants for more 
details.

Then inside your code refer to your assets using code like below:

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("awsconfiguration.json");
```

Reference:

1. [Android get file from asset/raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908648/android-get-file-from-asset-raw/45908819)
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Didn't even have to use sourceSets.

Comment: how to create awsconfiguration.json file for push notification ?